# Dynamic Top Bar Text Based on Current Page in Zurb Foundation for Apps App

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

*I am building a single page application using Zurb's Foundation for Applications and Angular.*

What is the recommended way to display different text in the top bar (nav bar) based on the current route?

For example, I would like to have the page title associated with current route appear in the Top Bar (a simple form of breadcrumbs).

I am following the standard app structure provided [Zurb's CLI tool](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/getting-started.html). My Top Bar is defined in index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Foundation for Apps](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/) framework uses [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). Therefore, to access router state information, for example, the name of the current route/page, use the following in an HTML template:

```
{{$state.current.name}}
```